# Convert DateTime Format to UTC DateTime Format C# Biztalk Mapping

Tags: c#, biztalk

I have a datetime in string format with the Format ( 2019-09-19T18:00:54.110 )

I want to convert the above datetime format to UTC format (yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss ) which is also a string format ,  I am not able to figure this out

Appreciate help !

This is what i have done so far ,

```
public string FormatDate(string inputDate)
        {
            System.DateTime strDate;
            if (System.DateTime.TryParseExact(inputDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out strDate))
            {
                return strDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
            }
            return "INVALID DATE";
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried?

Comment: I have edited with my code which i tried

Comment: UTC is not a format. UTC is date time. ISO is a format.

Comment: please also note that your input format does not specify a timezone, so getting it into a UTC could be problematic.

Comment: So how does what you have done so far not work?  Do you get an error?  Is the output not what is expected?  Please add some example inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the milliseconds as well, with the `f` format specifier. So you will end up with something like this:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:fff
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, c# has many amazing functions on DateTime. Simply try:

```
        var time = DateTime.Parse("2019 - 09 - 19T18: 00:54.110");
        var result = time.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss");
```

And if you want to check the input data, add a try&catch block!